# java.lang.StackOverflowError Running JSF 2 example on Weblogic 12c

Tags: java, jsf-2, weblogic, weblogic12c, stack-overflow

I followed the very basic tutorial found here [example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-hello-world-example/) and cannot seem to get past the following error:

```
Error 500--Internal Server Error 
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.addHeader(ServletResponseImpl.java:567)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.addHeader(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:200)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.addHeader(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:200)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.addHeader(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:200)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.addHeader(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:200)
```

**Pressing shift + F5 a couple times I can generate a slightly different stacktrace as follows:**

```
Error 500--Internal Server Error 
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerResponseWrapper.setStatus(ViewHandlerResponseWrapper.java:88)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.setStatus(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:224)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerResponseWrapper.setStatus(ViewHandlerResponseWrapper.java:88)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.setStatus(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:224)
```

**Here is my web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<display-name>JavaServerFaces</display-name>

<!-- JSF mapping -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Map these files with JSF -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**Here is the pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>JavaServerFaces</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>JavaServerFaces Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<dependencies>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>JavaServerFaces</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

I have exhausted several hours searching the web and constructing new projects with no luck. I understand that the StackOverflowError is produced from bad recursion calls and infinite loops, however I can't see this as the case here.

My current dev stack is eclipse juno, m2e-wtp, weblogic 12c, Java EE 6 using JSF 2.1

I am hoping it is something simple like a missing dependency or weblogic plugin in my pom.xml. Any help would me MUCH appreciated.

**UPDATE 1:** If I export the war file using eclipse (Right click the project -> Export -> WAR file) then manually deploy it via the weblogic admin counsel the app works as expected. More specifically the version of eclipse is the one from oracle (oepe-12.1.1.2.1-juno-distro-win32-x86_64.zip).

Comment: Have the jsp-api, jstl and servlet-api with provided scope. They should be already be shipped with weblogic.

Comment: Great tip! Should make the war file lighter. Unfortunately no help with the error..

Comment: where is the **"caused by"** bit of the stacktrace?

Comment: Unfortunately there is not a **"caused by"** section in the log. =/

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> Solved the problem! After adding JSF 2.1 in the pom.xml the JSF 2.1 checkbox was checked in project facets, however it did not add the faces-config.xml to the project. I simple created a new xml file named faces-config.xml under the webapp --> WEB-INF folder and added the following xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd" version="2.1">

<application></application>

</faces-config>
```

> I Hope this helps others!